# ASP.NET MVC5, JSON, popup partialView - set DropDownList selected

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc

i want to set the DDL selected item with item inserted in popup page.
Used script sample from here - http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1126/search-sort-paging-insert-update-and-delete-with-asp-net-mvc-and-bootstrap-modal-popup-part-2

in JsonResult i see the inserted value (checking in Debug mode with breakpoint), but **need help with setting this value as selected in DDL in main page.**

```
public ActionResult WorkPlaces(int id = 0)
        {
            var workPlace = new Work();
            return PartialView("WorkPlaces", workPlace);
        }
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult WorkPlaces(Work work)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       db.Works.Add(work);
       db.SaveChanges();
       return Json(new { success = true });
    }
       return Json(work, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Model classes

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Person Name")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> WorkId { get; set; }
    public virtual Work Work { get; set; }
}

public class Work
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Work place")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    public string workPlace { get; set; }
}
```

Main page

```
    @model testAppAuth.Models.Person

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    }

    <h2>Create</h2>


    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Person</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WorkId, "WorkId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("WorkId", null, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "form-control"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WorkId, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})

                <a class="btn btn-success" data-modal="" href="/Person/WorkPlaces" id="btnCreate">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>

    <!-- modal placeholder-->
    <div id='myModal' class='modal fade in'>
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div id='myModalContent'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @section scripts{
        @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Appjs/WorkPlace.js")
    }
```

popup page

```
    @model testAppAuth.Models.Work

    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 class="modal-title">Add new workplace</h3>
    </div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Work place</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.workPlace, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.workPlace, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.workPlace, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <span id="progress" class="text-center" style="display: none;">
            <img src="/images/wait.gif" alt="wiat" />
            Wait..
        </span>

        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save" />
        <button class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
    }


<script>
        $("form").removeData("validator");
        $("form").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
</script>
```

script for popup

```
$(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {
        $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
            $('#myModal').modal({
                keyboard: true
            }, 'show');
            bindForm(this);
        });
        return false;
    });
});

function bindForm(dialog) {
    $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
        $('#progress').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                    $('#progress').hide();
                    location.reload();
                } else {
                    $('#progress').hide();
                    $('#myModalContent').html(result);
                    bindForm();
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
}
```

**Also, with this script even i set [Required] attribute in Model classes, it closes if i click close button without filling fields. How to make it not to close?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your Question how to validate before closing the Model use the below code

```
$(function () {


$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var form = $("#formid");
    form.Validate();
    if(form.Valid()){
    //Ajax;
    }
    else{
    event.PreventDefault();
    }})});
```

Now in ajax Success used jquery to add value to DropDown

Answer (score 1):

Your first question:

You can do this using Jquery:

When you are closing the dialog(Sucess) make a Jquery call to a function that will take the submitted value and change the selected item in your main page.

ex:

```
 success: function (result) {
         //change the selected item
    }
```

Your second question:

The Ajax Call doesn't care about the Model Validation.

When you are submitting the data from your modal, validate the values of the required fields before making the AJAX Call.

ex.

```
 $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
if(isValidInput()){           
 $('#progress').show();

   //make Ajax Call

  }

});

function IsValidInput(){
//do validation
}
```